# How to stop TeamCity Agent Push resolve DNS entry

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to install a TeamCity build agent on a machine which has IP 123.123.123.123 and a DNS entry such as subdomain.ourdomain.com

When I do an Agent Push I enter the IP address and credentials for the server. However, when PsExec runs it goes off and finds the DNS entry for the server and uses that instead:

```
c:\TeamCity\temp\psexec-wrapper.exe /accepteula \\subdomain.ourdomain.com -e -h -u user.name -p ********** cmd.exe /C ver
```

This causes an invalid handle. However, if I go to command line and replace the domain with the IP address, it works.

Been looking everywhere, but I can't find a setting to as TeamCity to ignore the DNS entry and just use the IP.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a bug, I would recommend to submit issue to our tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/